# ASP.NET MVC refresh table in tab-pill

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with my solution.

I have 2 related classes and display them like the example [on the ASP.net -Webseite](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but only with one related class.

This class is displayed in  a [tab-pill](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills).

Now I added Modals and a Javascript to edit, delete and create new Entitys, [like This.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786085/Asp-Net-MVC-List-Editor-with-Bootstrap-Modals), but i don't know how to implement the refresh function, that only my table from the related class refresh and not the page. I will not lose the tab-pill, with is activated.

Thanks for help

**Here my View-Page:**

```
    @model Armageddon.Models.itUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details ";
}
@using Armageddon.Helpers;
<h2>Details:</h2>

<div>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-md-5" style="text-align:right">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.displayName)</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.displayName)</div>
</div>

<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Logins</a></li>
</ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="UIT2SysGroup">
                @if (Model.UIT2SystemGroup != null)
                {
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Gruppen</th>
                            <th>@Html.NoEncodeActionLink("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>", "Add", "Create", "UIT2SystemGroup", routeValues: new { PersonId = Model.itUserID }, htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right" })</th>
                        </tr>
                        @if (Model.UIT2SystemGroup.Count() != 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.UIT2SystemGroup)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.SystemGroup.Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                           @Html.NoEncodeActionLink("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>", "Delete", "Delete", "UIT2SystemGroup", routeValues: new { id = item.UIT2SystemGroupID}, htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", @class = "btn btn-danger" })

                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            <tr><td colspan="3"><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></div> Zurzeit sind keine administrativen Aufgaben vergeben.</div></td></tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                }
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Ajax to call the controller that is returning the view.

There is a good sample here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/

You could put your table inside a partial view and return this as part of your page.